# Probability calculation, system uptime, likelihood of occurence

Tags: probability, odds-ratio

(redirected here from mathoverflow.net)
Hello,

At work I was asked the probability of a user hitting an outage on the website. I have some following metrics. Total system downtime = 500,000 seconds a year. Total amount of seconds a year = 31,556,926 seconds. Thus, p of system down = 0.159 or 1.59%
We can also assume that downtime occurs evenly for a period of approximately 2 hours per week.

Now, here is the tricky part. We have a metric for amount of total users attempting to use the service = 16,000,000 during the same time-frame. However, these are subdivided, in the total time spent using the service. So, lets say we have 7,000,000 users that spend between 0 - 30 seconds attempting to use the service. So for these users what is the probability of hitting the system when it is unavailable? (We can assume an average of 15 seconds spent total if this simplifies things)

I looked up odds ratios and risk factors, but I am not sure how to calculate the probability of the event occurring at all.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I was given a possible answer, at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52816/probability-calculation-system-uptime-likelihood-of-occurence and was following the advice on posting the question in the most appropriate forum.

Comment: Pretty well posed question (+1 from me), I like the background context, it makes it easier to judge which assumptions are plausible to make.  I'll have a go at answering, post my answer at some point in the near future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so here is my answer that I promised.  I initially thought it would be quickish, but my answer has become quite large, so at the begining, I state my general results first, and leave the gory details down the bottom for those who want to see it.

I must thank @terry felkrow for this fascinating question - if I could give you +10 I would!  This basically is a prime example of the slickness and elegance of Bayesian and Maximum Entropy methods.  I have had much fun working it out!

SUMMARY

Exact result
$$Pr(\theta \in (0,S)|F_{obs},T_U,T_D)=1-\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)^{F_{obs}+1}$$

Where $\theta$ is the time of the first down time (in seconds) observed by the user, $T_U$ is the number of "up time" seconds observed , $T_D$ is the number of "down time" seconds observed, and $F_{obs}$ is the number of "down periods" (F for "failures"; $\frac{T_D}{F_{obs}}$ is the average number of seconds spent in "down time") observed

For your case, $F_{obs}$ is not given, but I would guess that you could find out what it was (which is why I gave the answer for known $F_{obs}$).  Now because you know $T_D$, this tells you a bit about $F_{obs}$, and you should be able to pose an "Expected Value" or educated guess of $F_{obs}$, call it $\hat{F}$.  Now using the geometric distribution with probability parameter $p=\frac{1}{\hat{F}}$ (this is the Maximum Entropy distribution for fixed mean equal to $\hat{F}$), to integrate out $F_{obs}$ gives the probability of (see details for the maths):

$$Pr(\theta \in (0,S)|\hat{F},T_U,T_D)=1-\frac{\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)^2}{\hat{F}-(\hat{F}-1)\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)}$$

So for your specific case, the table below shows various bounds for different $F$, assuming it is known (column 2) or "expected" (column 3).  Can see that the knowing $F_{obs}$ comparing to knowing a "rough" guess $\hat{F}$ only matters when it is very large, (i.e. when the observed average down time is 1 second or less).

$$ 
\begin{array}{c|c}
  F & Pr(\theta \geq \text{S}|F_{obs},T_U,T_D) & Pr(\theta \in (0,S)|\hat{F},T_U,T_D) \\
  \hline
  1,000,000 & 0.625 & 0.499 \\
  \hline
  500,000 & 0.393 & 0.336 \\
  \hline
  250,000 & 0.227 & 0.207 \\
  \hline
  125,000 & 0.128 & 0.122 \\
  \hline
  62,500 & 0.074 & 0.072 \\
  \hline
  31,250 & 0.045 & 0.045 \\
  \hline
  15,685 & 0.031 & 0.030 \\
  \hline
  7,812 & 0.023 & 0.023 \\
  \hline
  1 & 0.016 & 0.016
 \end{array}
$$

DETAILS

It is based on example 3 in the paper below

Jaynes, E. T., 1976. `Confidence Intervals vs Bayesian Intervals,' in Foundations of Probability Theory, Statistical Inference, and Statistical Theories of Science, W. L. Harper and C. A. Hooker (eds.), D. Reidel, Dordrecht, p. 175; [pdf](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/confidence.pdf)

It supposes that the probability that a machine will operate without failure for a time $t$, is given by
$$Pr(\theta \geq t)=e^{-\lambda t};\ \  0<t,\lambda < \infty$$
Where $\lambda$ is an unknown "rate of failure", to be estimated from some data.

I will use this to model the failure times in 2 separate cases.  Where "failure" indicates going from "working" to "down time", and the other way around.  You can think of this like modeling two "memoryless" proceedures.  We first "wait" for the down time, from time $t=t_{0u}=0$, to time $t=t_{1d}$ (so that there was $t_1$ seconds of uninterupted "operating" time).  This has a failure rate of $\lambda_d$ At time $t=t_{1d}$ a new process takes over and now we "wait" for the down time to "fail" at time $t=t{1u}$.  It is also supposed that the rate of failure is constant over time, and that the process has *independent increments* (i.e. if you know where the process is at time $t=s$, then all other information about the process prior to time $t<s$ is irrelevant).  This is what is known as a *first order Markov process*, also known as a "memoryless" process (for obvious reasons).

Okay, the problem goes as follows, Jaynes eq (8) gives the density that $r$ units out of $n$ will fail at the times $t_1 ,t_2 ,\dots,t_r$, and the remaining (n-r) do not fail at time t as
$$p(t_1 ,t_2 ,\dots,t_r | \lambda,n)=[\lambda^r exp(-\lambda \sum_{i}t_i)][exp(-(n-r)\lambda t)]$$
Then assigning a uniform prior (the particular prior you use won't matter in your case because you have so much data, the likelihood will dominate any reasonably "flat" prior) to $\lambda$, this give the a posterior predictive distribution of (see Jaynes paper for details, eq (9)-(13)):
$$Pr(\theta\geq\theta_0|n,t_1 ,\dots,t_r)=\int_0^{\infty}Pr(\theta\geq\theta_0|\lambda)p( \lambda | t_1 ,t_2 ,\dots,t_r,n)d\lambda=\Bigg(\frac{T}{T+\theta_0}\Bigg)^{r+1}$$

Where $T=\sum_{i}t_i + (n-r)t$ is the total time the devices operated without failure.  This indicates that you only needed to know the total "failure free time", which you have both given as $T_D=500,000$ and $T_U=31,556,926-500,000=31,056,926$.  Also for you problem we always observed either $n$ or $n-1$ "failures" by time $t$, depending on whether the system was "down" or "up" at time $t$.

Now if you knew what $F_{obs}$ was, then you just plug in $r=F_{obs}$ to the above equation.  The probability that a user will not be in the "down time" in the first $S$ seconds given that the system was "up" when they started is then

$$Pr(\theta\geq S|[\text{Up at start} ],F_{obs},T_U)=\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+30}\Bigg)^{F_{obs}+1}$$

But the story is not yet finished, because we can marginalise (remove conditions) further.  To make the equations shorter, let $A$ stand for *the system was up when the user started*, and let $B$ stand for *no down time in* $S$ *seconds*.  Then, by the law of total probability, we have

$$Pr(B|F_{obs},T_U,T_D)=Pr(B|F_{obs},T_U,T_D,A)Pr(A|F_{obs},T_U,T_D)$$
$$+Pr(B|F_{obs},T_U,T_D,\overline{A})Pr(\overline{A}|T_U,T_D)$$

Now $\overline{A}$ means that the system was down when the user started, so that it is impossible for $B$ to be true (i.e. no down time) when $\overline{A}$ is true.  Thus, $Pr(B|F_{obs},T_U,T_D,\overline{A})=0$, and we just have to multiply by $Pr(A|F_{obs},T_U,T_D)$.  This is given by $\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}$, because none of information contained in $F_{obs},T_U,T_D$ give any reason to favor any particular time over any other time.

$$Pr(\theta\geq S|F_{obs},T_U,T_D)=\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)^{F_{obs}+1}$$

Taking 1 minus this gives the desired result.

*NOTE: We may have additional knowledge which would favor certain times, such as knowing what time of day is more likely to have a system outage, or we may believe that system outage is related to the number of users; this analysis ignores such information, and so could be improved upon by taking it into account.*

NOTE: if you only knew the a rough guess of $F_{obs}$, say $\hat{F}$, you could (in theory) use the geometric distribution (has largest entropy for fixed mean) for $F_{obs}$ with probability parameter $p=\frac{1}{\hat{F}}$ and marginalise over $F_{obs}$ to give:

$$Pr(\theta \geq S|T_U,T_D)=\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\sum_{i=1}^{i=\infty} p(1-p)^{i-1}\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)^{i+1}$$
$$=\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)\sum_{i=1}^{i=\infty} p(1-p)^{i-1}\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)^{i}$$
$$=\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)\sum_{i=1}^{i=\infty} p(1-p)^{i-1} exp\Bigg(i log\Bigg[\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg]\Bigg)$$

Now the summation is just the moment generating function, $m_{X}(t)=E[exp(tX)]$, evaluated at $t=log\Bigg[\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg]$.  The [mgf for the geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) is given by:

$$m_{X}(t)=E[exp(tX)]=\frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}$$
$$\rightarrow m_{X}(log\Bigg[\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg])=\frac{p\Bigg[\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg]}{1-(1-p)\Bigg[\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg]}$$

And this gives a marginal probability of (noting $p=\frac{1}{\hat{F}}$):

$$Pr(\theta \geq S|T_U,T_D)=\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)\frac{\frac{1}{\hat{F}}\Bigg[\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg]}{1-(1-\frac{1}{\hat{F}})\Bigg[\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg]}$$

Rearranging terms gives the final result:
$$Pr(\theta \in (0,S)|T_U,T_D)=1-Pr(\theta \geq S|T_U,T_D)=1-\frac{\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)^2}{\hat{F}-(\hat{F}-1)\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)}$$

Comment: I think I just had a minor heart attack. I am digesting this right now, thank you so much. I wish I could upvote more than once!

Comment: let me know if I need to clarify anything.  It would be interesting to see how the results change if we assumed the rate of failure was non-constant, but sinusoidal - i.e. system is cyclical, with "good" and "bad" streaks.  You would probably need more info to make this kind of improvement work, such as the "transition times" - the time points when the system changed from "up" to "down" and "down" to "up".

Comment: @probabilityislogic It took me awhile, but I am pretty sure I grasped the $\hat{F}$ calculations, however, I am fairly stumped with the $F_{obs}$ data column. Let's say we are looking at $F$ failures of 1 second or less (total downtime of 500,000 and 1,000,000 "switches"). According to the first formula, to calculate the probability, the result is $$1-\frac{31056926}{31556926}\Bigg(\frac{31056926}{(1,000,000*30)+31056926}\Bigg)^{(500,000/1,000,000)+1}$$ but that yields a probability of $0.643$ for me vs. $0.625$ found in your table. Am I missing something obvious? And also is $S = F * 30$?

Comment: To add to the comment above, I do not think I understand the $F_{obs}$ quite well. If $F_{obs}$ stands for "number of down periods", then for $F = 1$ the $F_{obs}$ *should* be 1 as well. Unless of course $F_{obs} = F / T_D$ in which case we match at the $F = 1$ but not $F = 1,000,000$ (my P yielding 0.87)

Comment: @terry - for your first question, $S=30$ in your case, because you want the probability of $\theta$ (actual time of first failure) being between $0$ and $S$.  The $(1,000,000*30)$ should be replaced by $30$.  And the power should be raised to $F_{obs}+1=1,000,001$, not $\frac{500,000}{1,000,000}+1=\frac{3}{2}$.  So correct form is: $1-\frac{31056926}{31556926}\Bigg(\frac{31056926}{\textbf{30}+31056926}\Bigg)^{\textbf{1,000,000}+1}$.  Which equals 0.625 (I double checked just to be sure).

Comment: @terry - clarification about $\hat{F}$ and $F_{obs}$.  The difference is that $F_{obs}$ indicates you actually know the number of failures which occurred (i.e. you know that the $T_D=500,000$ seconds of down time was caused by *exactly* $F_{obs}$ failures).  When using $\hat{F}$, you are *uncertain* about the precise number of failures, but you expect it to be $\hat{F}$.  Mathematically, it is $E(F_{obs}|\hat{F})=\hat{F}$, where the expectation is taken over your *uncertainty* about $F_{obs}$ (it is the *uncertainty* which is distributed, $F_{obs}$ is a fixed unknown constant).

Comment: @terry-just to add to your comment, yes when $\hat{F}=1$ this implies $F_{obs}=1$, and my equations reflect that the probability is the same regardless of which one you use:
$$1-\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)^{1+1}=1-\frac{\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+T_D}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)^2}{1-(1-1)\Bigg(\frac{T_U}{T_U+S}\Bigg)}$$
This is a good "common sense" check that the calculations are sound.  Also another example of the coherence of Bayesian methodology (when things should be equal, they are equal *automatically*, a property which never ceases to amaze me).